# <ul> display: table not working some of the time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project, and I need the buttons on the page to be the same size. I got it to work. but only some of the time. As you can see the top set of buttons are not the same size, but the bottom set are the same height. The HTML code for the same in every way except that the bottom has `class="third"` on the third button, and the top has four items.

I tested, and the `class="third"` does not cause the difference.

The only thing i can think of is that there is something about having 4 buttons causes the height to stop working.

```css
body {
  background: #fff2e8;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5% auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20vh;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

li#small {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

li.third {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.ghost-button {
  color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
  border: 1px solid rgb(9, 82, 85);
  padding: 5px 5px;
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.HP {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 2% 5% 0 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 2.5%;
}

.ghost-button:hover,
.ghost-button:active {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(9, 82, 85);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.third a {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="ghost-button" href="S5A.php">Try
   calling the number listed on the document</a></li>
  <li><a class="ghost-button" href="S5B.php">Keep
   the document on your counter and wait until your daughter comes by to
   visit</a></li>
  <li><a class="ghost-button" href="S5C.php">Ignore
   the document</a></li>
  <li><a class="ghost-button" href="S5D.php">Ask
   Your Service Coordinator for Help</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a class="ghost-button" href="S1A.php">Check the newspaper classifieds for affordable pieces </a></li>
<li><a class="ghost-button" href="S1B.php">Check for garage 
sales within walking distance </a></li>
<li class="third"><a class="ghost-button" href="S1C.php">Do 
nothing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried to give a height in px instead of %?

Comment: The problem being that this need to be able to scale to different screen sizes, and if I use pixel dimensions it will have a very difficult time converting to mobile, or tablets

Comment: The bottom set are not the same height. In your example, the height is a function of the amount of text and where it wraps. You may need to consider setting a min-height in `em`s for each button. Or dump the floats and try CSS flexbox as then you have more control over heights in a flex row.

Comment: @aardrian `flexbox` won't help when it comes to equal height control, since there is more than 1 line

Comment: @aardrian in the bottom set, the buttons next to each other are at least the same height, but in the top they aren't. I have used flexes for at least some of it to get them to have vertically centered text

Comment: Using `display: table` on the `ul` and then give its children (the `li`) `display: block` kind of kills the purpose to use `display: table` in the first place. If you could post a picture of the expected result we will be able to suggest a proper solution

Comment: The bottom set is the way the top is supposed to look. I'll try removing the display:block from the children though.

Comment: The bottom section is not the same height if you are looking at it on a smaller screen.

Comment: @Pango Yes, I have some media queries that change it completely if it is below 900px. I'm just trying to figure out what causes the difference

Comment: @Lordbug something like this??? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/4mx9L7gc/1/

Comment: @Daniel H Yes, actually. Thank you. I saw that you declared the height with vh. Do you know why it was being problematically different before?

Comment: @Lordbug it is normal. sometime you have long sentence that will wrap it will increase the height automatically unless you set a fixed height. play around with it and see what you need.

Comment: @Lordbug you might want to checkout this, might fit your needs. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/